# VirtualBox.app would no longer run

Tags: macos, mac, mojave, virtualbox

Results in `About This Mac`:

```
macOS Mojave
Version 10.14.1
MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
```

This hardware shipped the OS version 10.10 Yosemite, if I remember correctly.

In either the Mojave update or the High Sierra update (I think it wasn't as early as by the Sierra update), `VirtualBox.app` stopped being runnable. I'm pretty sure this was still functioning by the time El Capitan was running.

The `VirtualBox.app` appears grayed out when finding it on Spotlight. When hitting it, it won't start normally as it did once upon a time, and the message is:

```
You can't use this version of the application "VirtualBox
.app" with this version of macOS.

You have "VirtualBox.app" 5.0.0.

[?] [OK]
```

I guess I'll install an up to date build of the same major version 5. It's going to be a bit painful because I should back up the virtual machine before the update, and it's big. But...

Before I do that, **can I get any better reporting message of the problem? Or do you know what is happening?**

The binaries in `/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/` seem to be all 64 bit.

Comment: Have you check the messages in `console`  app?

Comment: It seems `/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VirtualBox` runs and splashes the "Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager"!

Comment: All virtual machines fail to open with exit code 1 (`NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)`).

Comment: There is also a message about a missing kernel driver and/or module not installed `rc=-1908`. This last message seems easier to troubleshoot searching in the Internet. :)

Comment: Looks like a security issue. I have provided an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in [VirtualBox v5.2.14](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog) ([bug #17805](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17805))

[Download](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) the latest version of VirtualBox for Mojave compatability

Comment: I backed up my virtual machines, I installed the latest version for that same major version, and it worked nicely well right from the beginning. This is not news, or it shouldn't, but when speaking of virtual machines, better be cautious.

Comment: *I backed up my virtual machines....*  Music to my ears.  Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `system preference` -> `security & privacy` -> `general` and check if you see the following message

[image]

If so, press `Allow...` and follow the instructions there.

Comment: I saw this same trouble shotting in a Medium blog, but no... there was no alert like that one.